# javascript equivalent for python ctypes with node-gyp

Tags: node.js, dll, node-gyp

I want to transform a python script into a javascript script. My python script loads a dll and use its API.

```
processings2D = ctypes.CDLL('processings2D.dll')
print(processings2D.ImageProcessor2DCreate())
```

I try do to the same with node-gyp but my script doesn't find the dll.

```
console.log(processings2D.ImageProcessor2DCreate());
                      ^
TypeError: Cannot load processings2D.dll library
```

test.js

```
var processings2D = require('./build/Release/processings2D.node');   
console.log(processings2D.ImageProcessor2DCreate());
```

addon.cc

```
#include <nan.h>
#include "processings2D/processings2D.h"

HINSTANCE hDLL = NULL;
typedef int(*Fn)();

void ImageProcessor2DCreate(const Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
    hDLL = LoadLibrary("processings2D.dll");
    if(!hDLL)
    {
        Nan::ThrowTypeError("Cannot load processings2D.dll library");
        return;
    }

    Fn fn = (Fn)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "ImageProcessor2DCreate");
    if (!fn) {
        Nan::ThrowTypeError("Could not load ImageProcessor2DCreate function");
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        return;
    }

    info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(fn()));
}

void Init(v8::Local<v8::Object> exports) {
    exports->Set(Nan::New("ImageProcessor2DCreate").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>(ImageProcessor2DCreate)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(twoD, Init)
```

binding.gyp

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "processings2D",
      "sources": [
        "addon.cc"
      ],
      "include_dirs": [
        "<!(node -e \"require('nan')\")"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

dll is in the Release folder `/build/Release/processings2D.dll`

**Am I in the right direction ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was really simple :

My dll was a 32 bit version, so I should build my module with the 32 bit `arch` flag and execute my test with the 32 bit version of node.

```
node-gyp clean configure --arch=ia32 build
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" test.js
```